# mysql.connector для python3

Tags: mysql, python, debian

Система Debian. Вопрос собственно в чем... Командой aptitude install python-mysql.connector установил коннектор, но дело в том, что работает он только для версии 2.7. Скорее всего, потому что она установлена по умолчанию. Дак вот, вопрос в том, как установить тот же модуль но для python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить модуль **python3-pip** и использовать соответственно **pip3**